# Hiding specific words in HTML div without losing style/format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to hide specific words in an HTML div without losing format in javascript/jquery. This is what I've tried but it messes with the style/format. 
HTML code:

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="ctl00_ctl40_g_fa7fc6e0_693d_4dde_91fd_1dbe1d7d0e76_ctl00_ListForm2_formFiller_ctl02" 
class="summary">Count the number of texts:
<ul><li>Text 0</li>
<li>Text 1</li><li>Text 2</li>
<li>Text 3</li><li>Text 4</li>
<li>Text 5</li></ul>
</div>
```

JS code:

```
$(function() {
   $('.summary').each(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
 $this.html($this.text().replace(/\bCount \bthe \bnumber \bof \btexts\b/g, '<b>Texts:</b>'));
});

});
```

I have also created a JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sLa3dkdd/). Please try running it without JS function first and then with the JS function to understand what I mean by style/format.

Comment: Why not use $this.html($this.html().replace(/\bCount \bthe \bnumber \bof \btexts\b/g, '<b>Texts:</b>')); ?

Comment: yes! that worked. thanks @juvian post it below so I can choose at as an answer.

Comment: Why not just wrap the text in a span.... Much easier, cleaner and probably faster.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon which text? the html text? It is auto generated from sharepoint out of the box therefore I'm using whatever I can from scripts to customize it to be user friendly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are replacing the html with only the text content changed, so you keep the text but loose all html elements. This way you can keep the html:

```
$this.html($this.html().replace(/\bCount \bthe \bnumber \bof \btexts\b/g, '<b>Texts:</b>'));
```

A nicer way of doing this is just to replace the text node content:

```
$('.summary').contents().first()[0].textContent='Texts:';
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you wanted?

```
$(function() {
  $('.summary').each(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
  $this.html($this.html().replace(/\bCount \bthe \bnumber \bof \btexts\b/g, '<b>Texts:</b>'));
  });

});
```

You should be replacing the html not the text nodes.
http://jsfiddle.net/sLa3dkdd/1/